# font awesome with primefaces 5.2

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, fonts

primefaces 5.2

i cant get font awesome to work with primefaces, i have setup the context param inside the web.xml file as so

```
   <context-param>
   <param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
   </context-param>
```

and i tried to use it like this

```
<p:commandButton  value="Capture" icon="fa fa-camera-retro"/>
<p:commandButton value="Edit" icon="fa fa-edit" type="button"/>
```

but instead of showing me the icon it is showing a ^, i saw a similar post here and tried the suggestions posted by including the following in a css

```
.ui-icon.fa {
 text-indent:0px;
 background-image:none;}
```

and

```
.ui-icon {
text-indent: 0;}
```

but neither of them worked for me. i am not sure if i am missing a step, i have not included the css or jar for font awesome because i am quite sure it comes built in in primefaces 5.2

Comment: did you check the console/network logging of the browser?

Comment: @Kukeltje yes, doesnt show anything

Comment: can you see `font-awesome.css` in the resources tab of your browser's developer console?

Comment: @Zim in firefox under the developer console in the style editor it only shows theme.css.jsf and primefaces.css.jsf

Comment: Are you sure the context param is in the right place? Aren't you using a snapshot version of PF5.2?

Comment: @Zim the context param is in the web.xml and i am using primefaces 5.2

Answer (score 8):

apparently i had to add the mime-type in the web.xml file. this isnt really mentioned in any of the documentation. the answer is from the following [link](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=42002&p=132218&hilit=font%20awesome#p132218)

this is what i added

```
    <mime-mapping>
    <extension>eot</extension>
    <mime-type>application/vnd.ms-fontobject</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>  
    <extension>otf</extension>  
    <mime-type>font/opentype</mime-type>  
</mime-mapping>      
<mime-mapping>  
    <extension>ttf</extension>  
    <mime-type>application/x-font-ttf</mime-type>  
</mime-mapping>      
<mime-mapping>  
    <extension>woff</extension>  
    <mime-type>application/x-font-woff</mime-type>  
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>  
    <extension>svg</extension>  
    <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>  
</mime-mapping>
```

Comment: For `woff2` include this
`<mime-mapping>
        <extension>woff2</extension>
        <mime-type>application/font-woff2</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using PF 6.0 on Glassfish 4 and after long trial and error search finally found out that the following css definition

```
html *
{
   font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif, Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif !important;
}
```

was interfering with **font awesome** so that the icons were displayed broken. Removing that piece of the css code solved the problem. I hope that helps.

Comment: Well, it is not 'interfering', it is just overriding the font that is used, everywhere. Therefore **never** use !important unless really needed and only in already very detailed selectors (never in a * ;-))

Answer (score 0):

What I found, sometimes the Primefaces configuration on web.xml is not working well. Like I integrate Primefaces with Spring Boot eventually my font awesome isn't working.

Here I mention one generic solution which is suitable for Spring/Spring boot.
In that case, you just need to use the CDN in your template.xhtml (which is the layout main file).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
```

In this solution, you don't need to any maven dependency on your pom.xml or web.xml file.

- PrimeFaces 7.0
- Spring Boot 2.1.8-realease